# Javascript for downloading csv file doesn't work in FireFox

Tags: javascript, csv

I've got a javascript for converting the data and save it as a csv file. It looks like this:

```
function downloadCSV(args) {
    var data, filename, link;
    var type = args.type;
    var fields = Object.keys(json_for_export[0]);
    var csv = json_for_export.map(function(row){
        return fields.map(function(fieldName){
            return '"' + (row[fieldName] || '') + '"';
            });
        });
   csv.unshift(fields);
   csv = csv.join('\r\n')
   if (csv == null) return;
   filename = 'csv' + '_' + args.filename || 'export.csv';
   if (!csv.match(/^data:text\/csv/i)) {
            csv = 'data:text/csv;charset=utf-8,' + '\uFEFF' + csv;
   }
   data = encodeURI(csv);
   link = document.createElement('a');
   link.setAttribute('href', data);
   link.setAttribute('download', filename);
   link.click();
}
```

It works fine in Chrome Browser but doesn't work in Firefox. What can be a cause of the problem?
A check into the console and the data is formatted well into a csv type.

Comment: Which version of Firefox?

Comment: Do you get any console errors? How is downloadCSV being called?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to append the `a` element to the DOM before clicking it:

```
document.body.appendChild(link);
link.click();
```

And after that you can immediately remove it:

```
document.body.removeChild(link);
```

Comment: Confirmed in 2019 for Firefox 67.0b11. Thanks!